# SystemParameter in MSDN example

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a window Chrome with button, but I am not able to get title text and image, there is an example of MSDN for this but it has some keyword not working in VS2015

```
<Style x:Key="StandardStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
<Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
    <Setter.Value>
        <WindowChrome />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="White"
                        Margin="{Binding Source={x:Static **SystemParameters2.Current**}, Path=WindowNonClientFrameThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Margin="36,8,0,0"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Icon}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(WindowChrome.WindowChrome).ResizeBorderThickness}" 
                       Width="{Binding Source={x:Static shell:SystemParameters2.Current}, Path=SmallIconSize.Width}"
                       WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

what is "SystemParameters2.Current" in this example? Is it some system parameter or user defined?
[Example by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS2015 / .NET Framework 4.5 there is a `SystemParameters` class available in the `PresentationFramework` assembly that contains the `WindowNonClientFrameThickness` and `SmallIconWidth` properties so the equivalent would be:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="White"
                    Margin="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WindowNonClientFrameThickness}}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Title}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           Margin="36,8,0,0"/>
    <Image ...
                       Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth}"
                       WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
</Grid>
```